# MDX running total by month

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to calculate cumulative transactions counts by month within quarter using MDX. How can I achieve this.

[image: Image of result to be achieved.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a proper date dimension set up, you can use the [QTD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/qtd-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) function to accomplish this.